# Exception With Jedis Pipeline

Tags: java, redis, jedis

When I use jedis like  code below:

```
public class JedisTest extends Sync {
    private static final String _SET_KEY_1 = "test1";
    private static final String _SET_KEY_2 = "test2";

    public void process() throws SQLException {
        Set<String> appSet = getAllUserableAppkey();
        final ShardedJedis jedis = RedisHelper.getJedis();
        final ShardedJedisPipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();

        for (String key : appSet) {
            Set<String> result = jedis.smembers(_SET_KEY_1);
            Set<String> result2 = jedis.smembers(_SET_KEY_2);
            String rangName = String.format("%s::%s", "test", key);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                pipeline.sadd(rangName, String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
        pipeline.sync();
    }

    public Set<String> getAllUserableAppkey() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DbHelper.init();
        RedisHelper.init();
        JedisTest jedisTest = new JedisTest();
        try {
            jedisTest.process();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It throw the Exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:224)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:217)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.smembers(Jedis.java:1055)
    at redis.clients.jedis.ShardedJedis.smembers(ShardedJedis.java:339)
    at com.snda.sync.impl.test.JedisTest.process(JedisTest.java:29)
    at com.snda.sync.impl.test.JedisTest.main(JedisTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I can modify the code to correct like :

```
public void process() throws SQLException {
    Set<String> appSet = getAllUserableAppkey();
    final ShardedJedis jedis = RedisHelper.getJedis();
    for (String key : appSet) {
        final ShardedJedisPipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
        Set<String> result = jedis.smembers(_SET_KEY_1);
        Set<String> result2 = jedis.smembers(_SET_KEY_2);
        //log.warn("result1 :{},result2:{}",result,result2);
        String rangName = String.format("%s::%s", "test", key);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pipeline.sadd(rangName, String.valueOf(i));
        }
        pipeline.sync();
    }
}
```

But I dont know why that exception throw , ,does `pipline.sadd()` conflict with `jedis.smembers` ? 
Thanks for answer me!

The jedis is latest:2.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use Jedis instance directly while pipelined.

Pipeline uses Jedis instance' stream (not initializing new stream), and since normal operation reads response immediately and pipeline reads whole responses later, mixing up two usages gets Jedis into trouble.

P -- Pipelined / N -- Normal

Request --> P(1) P(2) N(3) N(4) P(5)

Redis Response --> P(1) P(2) N(3) N(4) P(5)

Matched request-response --> N(1 : should be 3) N(2 : should be 4) P(3 : should be 1) P(4 : should be 2) P(5)

You can see response can be easily flawed.

Comment: Thank you for answer ,in the first example code , I use the fresh jedis instance to do normal ,and anther to do pipeline,and it worked.